# Is there a way to make some entries in history "sticky"?

Tags: bash, history

I use the `history` / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> thing quite a bit, but from time to time either

- a command I use regularly (but not regularly enough, apparently)
  "fades out" behind my command history threshold, or
- some system hang-up caused me to hard-reset the machine and the
  history log becomes a garbled mess

Now is there a way to make entries in history "stick", so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> doesn't rely on a specific pattern to be present in history log? Can I define "default entries" in my .dotfiles somewhere, like `.bashrc`, or history's config?

I know there's the option to have the history threshold set to infinity, but I don't want that.

Answer (score 2):

I used to be heavily reliant on using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to recall previously entered commands – both commonly used commands and long complicated ones. I encountered very similar issues to those you describe.

To overcome these problems, I modified my Bash configuration so that when the shell exits it appends to the history file rather than over-write it:

```
shopt -s histappend
```

However, if the shell didn’t exit cleanly (as in a hard reset), I’d still lose the history for that session so I added the following to save the history after each command is entered.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
```

#### Shell aliases

In the end, I came to embrace [shell aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28Unix_shell%29) as the best way to save the commonly used commands and those long complicated ones that take time to get right. As long as they’re saved to my aliases file, they’ll *always* be available to me – even years later.

I store all my aliases in `~/.bash_aliases` and then source that file from  my `.bashrc` as suggested by the default `.bashrc` provided by Ubuntu:

```
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Comment: That bit about `.bash_aliases` is also in the default `.bashrc`.

Comment: @muru That's where I got the idea. Cygwin's default also has something very similar. I've now edited my question to provide attribution -- and thanks for the keyboard tags.

Comment: So the answer is: "No"? No way to make commands sticky?? ;) -- Well, the second part of your post is very helpful, as a workaround seems to be the only way. Apart from shell aliases, I had the idea to have a small startup-script that injects my list of common commands into history's log every now and then. -- The first part is a discussion I've already heard when I first encountered a garbled history log and investigated solutions, but I'm not such a fan of histappend or even write after each command... Seems I just have to keep handy commands separate of history somewhere.

Comment: Indeed, for Gentoo `histappend` is a system default since long ago https://bugs.gentoo.org/139609

Answer (score 1):

Not sticky, but prolong their life in history:

```
#store not 2k commands but 20k, feel free to increase if needed
export HISTFILESIZE=20000
export HISTSIZE=20000
#don't store duplicates, so save some space too
export HISTCONTROL="ignoredups"
```

Should be added to .bashrc

And yes, aliases are very helpful.